# Android Studio fails to connect to a backend server

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm developing mobile app in Android Studio with Kotlin, and backend in ASP.NET web api. When I execute my app on emulator, and try to connect to a backend with address **"http://10.0.2.2:5248"** it works ,but when I execute mu app on mobile, paired with usb or wifi, it doesn't work.

I'have tried to change adress to a **"http://localhost:5248"** , **"http://127.0.0.1:5248"** , my ip adress **"http://ipadress"**, but nothing works. I have internet permission in manifest.xml, but when i try to connect i get exception

**java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to @/pcIpAdress (port 5248) from @/mobileIpAddress (port 44160) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)**

Comment: You need to make sure that your server is configured to serve content on your non-`localhost` IP address and your designated port. `http://10.0.2.2:5248` on an emulator says "use the computer's `localhost` and port 5248, for an emulator *running on that same computer*". A phone is running separately from that computer, so `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I understand the problem now, but do you know how can I configure my IP address to works the same as running from emulator? @CommonsWare

Comment: You might wish to search on that in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) and ask a question there if you cannot find an answer.

Comment: `Android Studio fails to connect to a backend server`  You mean: My Android app fails to connect to a backend server.

Comment: `my ip adress "http://ipadress",` Unclear. Is that a local LAN address or a public internet ip address and hence the public ip of your router? Also you did not tell if mobile used wifi aor simcard.